# need help converting C# code to javascript / reversing a function output

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm working on a function that converts a number to string and string to a number.

the original c# code

```
public static string unhash(Int64 hash)
{
    string originalString = "";
    Int64 mod = 37;
    string letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";
    while (hash != 7)
    {
        Int64 index = hash % mod;
        originalString = letters[(Int32) index] + originalString; // need help converting this line to javascript
        hash = (hash - index) / mod;
    }
    return originalString;
}
```

the javascript code
this is working correctly as it convert string into hash that I want

```
function hash (s) {
    var h = 7;
    var  letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        h = (h * 37 + letters.indexOf(s[i]))
    }
    return h;
}
```

the code to reverse the process of hash to string, it not working correctly

```
function unhash (hash) {
    var originalString = "";
    var mod = 37;
    var letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";
    while( hash != 7) {
        var index = hash % mod;
        originalString = letters[(Int32Array)index] + originalString; // I'm not sure what the javascript version of int32
        hash = (hash - index) / mod;
    }
}
alert(hash("leepadg")); // this is the correct output 680131659347 
alert(unhash( 680131659347)); //output supposed to be leepadg but returning undefined
```

Comment: Your unhash function is not returning anything. That is why it is undefined.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean in JavaScript?: `(Int32Array)index`  You don't do casting in a dynamic language, nor is `Int32Array` anything in JavaScript.

Comment: I hasn't sure what to put in place (Int32) index from the javascript. so I tried Int32Array.  I don't know what to put in place for that section.  Thank @rasmeister, I didn't noticed I forgot to put return statement..

Comment: No need to do any "casting". You can just do `letters[index]`.

Comment: thank you so much, it is working correctly now